# Typescript: Limit Return Value but not Parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wish to pass in a function as a parameter but limit the passed function's return type but not its parameters.

Ex: function Car(driver: Function), where driver can be ()=>boolean or (first, second) => boolean. The driver must take a function with return type boolean but have any number of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

`FactoryFunction<T>` specifies function type with arbitrary arguments, but a return type of `T` (or a subtype thereof).

Demo: https://repl.it/@chvolkmann/IdealisticLiveRelationaldatabase

```js
abstract class Vehicle {} // abstract is optional
class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Truck extends Vehicle {}

type FactoryFunction<T> = (...args: any[]) => T

function importVehicle(factory: FactoryFunction<Vehicle>) {
  const vehicle = factory() // type: Vehicle
  console.log(vehicle)
}

importVehicle(() => new Car())
importVehicle(() => new Truck())
```

EDIT:
You can also make the function itself generic.

```js
function importSomething<T>(factory: FactoryFunction<T>) {
  const obj = factory() // type: T
  console.log(obj)
}

importSomething(() => new Car())
```

Comment: This can be a solution so I marked it for now, but this assumes that you know the type at compile time. I wish for the function to be dynamically injected with a function that requests any number of parameters and must return a single type.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you use a generic function, you don't need to know the types at compile time. Hope that helps!